Implementing Governance, Vesting, and Airdrop for an SPL Token on Solana Without Custom Contracts
I am in the process of creating a token on the Solana blockchain and aim to incorporate governance, vesting, and airdrop functionalities. My goal is to achieve this by leveraging existing Solana programs and standards, thereby avoiding the need to develop any new smart contracts.
For the token creation and management, I plan to use the SPL Token standard. Regarding governance, I have identified the governance program available in the Solana Program Library (Governance) that integrates with SPL tokens.
I have a few specific questions:
Firstly, is there an existing program or a well-established pattern within the Solana ecosystem that supports token vesting compatible with SPL tokens? Additionally, how can I ensure that tokens locked in a vesting schedule remain eligible for governance voting?
Secondly, are there reliable tools or solutions available for conducting airdrops on Solana that work seamlessly with SPL tokens? I am also interested in understanding the best practices to manage airdrop distributions without compromising the security of the tokens or the integrity of the governance process.
Lastly, how can I effectively integrate governance, vesting, and airdrop functionalities using the existing Solana programs to create a cohesive token ecosystem? Are there any potential limitations or important considerations I should be aware of when combining these features using pre-built solutions?
I prefer to use well-audited and community-supported programs. It is crucial that token holders retain the ability to participate in governance even while their tokens are vested.
